# DynamoDB "composite" keys index structure

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to model a "simple" table of 3 columns:

`userId | topicId | views`

The table should be able to:

- have repeating `userId`
- have repeating `topicId`
- enforce unique combination of `userId` and `topicId`

In other words, there are many `topicId`'s associated with a `userId`, and `views` will be a number that is incremented.

How would I create my indexes if I need to do the following queries:

- get a list of records for provided `userId`
- get and update one unique record for provided `userId and topicId`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have more topicIds than userIds you should create your table with:

hash key - **topicId**

range key - **userId**

Add a global secondary index with:

hash key - **userId**

range key - **topicId**

You can then insert and update records using the combo topicId + userId and query for lists of topics for a specific user id.